# Array of inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an Inventory class in which I would like to make an array with objects from the classes Sword, Shield and Potion.

```
class Inventory {
public:
    Inventory();
    ~Inventory();
    virtual void add();
    Inventory** getinvent();
    void setinvent(Inventory** new_inventory);
    int getsize();
    void setsize(int new_size);
private:
    Inventory** inventory;
    int invent_size;
};

Inventory::Inventory() {
    inventory = new Inventory*[1];
    invent_size = 1;
}

class Sword : public Inventory {
public:
    Sword(int strength);
    ~Sword();
    void add();
private:
    int strength;
    Sword* sword;
};

Sword::Sword(int strength) {
    this->strength = strength;
    sword = this;
}

void Sword::add() {
    setsize(getsize() + 1);

    Inventory** new_invent = new Inventory*[getsize()];
    for (int i = 0; i < getsize() - 1; i++) {
        new_invent[i] = getinvent()[i];
    }

    new_invent[getsize() - 1] = sword;
    setinvent(new_invent);
}
```

The Shield and Potion classes are similar to the Sword class. If I make the following objects in the implementation:

```
Inventory* inventory = new Inventory();
Sword* sword = new Sword(1);
```

How do I now add this sword to this specific inventory? I don't think sword->add(); would work, since sword doesn't know it's inherited from inventory. Is this correct?
I tried to make the add() method virtual, since it has to work for sword, shield and potion objects.

Comment: why do the items inherit from `Inventory` ?

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental problem with this design. The only mechanism for adding an item to an inventory is `add()` which can only add an item to itself. The concept of a sword being an inventory is strange.

Comment: Your class hierarchy is confusing -- how is it that a `Sword` *is an* `Inventory`? And why would an `Inventory` contain other `Inventory`'s?

Comment: Why does your Inventory class contain an array pointers to Inventory? This would make since for a data structure like a list, but your code looks dangerously circular.

Comment: you probably want something like `InventoryItem` as base class and then maybe a simple `std::vector<InventoryItem*>` will do (or replace `*` with your favourite smart pointer)

Comment: I see you're new to SO. Don't forget to vote and mark the question you find most useful as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic polymorphism, we can create an abstract class `Item`, which describes the functionality an item has in an inventory. It's useful because, with such class, it's possible to manage items we don't know about, we only know that they will behave like one.

```
class Item
{
public:
    virtual ~Item() = default;
    virtual const char* description() const = 0;
};
```

Going further, all other items (swords, bottles etc) can inherit from this class, thus giving them the characteristic of being an item:

```
class Sword: public Item
{
public:
    Sword() = default;
    virtual ~Sword() = default;
    const char* description() const override
    { return "Sword"; }
};
```

In the `description` method, it's overridden the `Item::description` abstract one, so whenever you call `.description` from an instance of `Sword`, you'll have the `"Sword"` string returned. For example:

```
Sword sword{};
Item& item = sword;
std::puts(item.description()); // prints the "Sword" string.
```

It's now simpler to store items, we just have to use a vector of them: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> inventory{};
inventory.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Sword>());
```

But why can't we have an `std::vector<Item>`? Simply because it's not possible to construct an `Item` from a `Sword`. Actually, it's not possible to even construct an `Item`, because it has abstract methods (i.e. they are there only to describe the method's prototype, not its definition/implementation).

`std::unique_ptr` is one of the few C++ smart pointers, it's there so we don't have to manually handle allocations. Using `new` and `delete` in your code can result in memory leaks and disasters because of the programmer's distraction, so a smart pointer makes this problem inexistent.

Finally, in order to have an item back, you may simply down-cast the thing back to a Sword:

```
const auto& item = inventory[0]; // item is `const std::unique_ptr<Item>&`
puts(item->description()); // prints "Sword"
puts(dynamic_cast<Sword*>(item.get())->description()); // also prints "Sword"
```

The latter (using dynamic_cast) will create a transformed pointer to that first item, from `item.get()` [method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get), but in the form of `Sword*`. You'll want to do this if there is a method or data member from `Sword` that isn't common to `Item`. For example, if you had something like "int sword_power`, you'd do this:

```
auto sword = dynamic_cast<Sword*>(item.get());
if (sword != nullptr)
{
    std::printf("sword power: %d\n", sword->sword_power);
}
```

Of course, checking if the cast was successful is optional, but doing that prevents your code from performing undefined behavior (in case the cast fails and a null pointer is returned).

There's still another way of doing this system (**not** prior to C++17), using the new library tool `std::variant`.

Basically, a variant lets you have one of many different types at a time. Different from tuples, that lets you have many different types (like a struct), a variant will only let one value from one type at a time. For better understanding it, here's how it works:

```
#include <variant> // C++17

struct Sword {};
struct Bottle {};

std::variant<Sword, Bottle> item = Sword{};
```

Like a `std::tuple`, a variant will have its possible types in the template parameters as arguments (i.e. the `Sword` and `Bottle` types are part of `item`'s whole type). This way, you can have either a sword OR a bottle at a time, but **never both at the same time**. Let's implement our inventory with that new functionality. First we have to change our classes a bit:

```
class Sword
{
public:
    int power;

    Sword() = default;
    const char* description() const
    { return "Sword"; }
};

class Bottle
{
public:
    bool empty;

    Bottle() = default;
    const char* description() const
    { return "Bottle"; }
};
```

We removed the need of virtual methods and dynamic polymorphism, and you'll further see that we won't need dynamic allocation anymore, as `std::variant` is required to work in the stack (which means program will be faster also (maybe)).

Now, for the `Item` concept, we make an alias of variant with our classes:

```
using Item = std::variant<Sword, Bottle>;
```

And we can use this with a vector too:

```
std::vector<Item> inventory{};
inventory.emplace_back(Sword{});
inventory.emplace_back(Bottle{});
```

There are a few ways of interacting with those items in case you need them back. One is to use `std::holds_alternative`:

```
auto& item = inventory[0];

if (std::holds_alternative<Sword>(item))
{
    auto& sword = std::get<Sword>(item);
    sword.power = 42;
    std::printf("%s: %d\n", sword.description(), sword.power);
}
```

It checks whether an object of a variant is holding the value of a giving type. In this case, we checked for `Sword`. Then, if there's a sword in there, we get the value using `std::get<>`, which returns a reference to our item as a `Sword`.

Another way of getting access of the real object is by using [std::visit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). Simply put: visitors are objects that behave like a function with overloads. You can call a visitor just like a function. In order to make a visitor, we can either use a struct with overloaded `operator()`s, or lambdas. Here's the first approach:

```
struct VisitItem
{
    void operator() (Sword& sword) const
    {
        std::printf("%s: %d\n", sword.description(), sword.power);
    }

    void operator() (Bottle& bottle) const
    {
        std::printf("%s: %s\n", bottle.description(),
                    bottle.empty? "empty" : "full");
    }
};

auto& item = inventory[0];
std::visit(VisitItem{}, item); // we give an instance of VisitItem for std::visit, and the item itself.
```

Here, `std::visit` will call the correct `operator()` for the current object inside the variant (i.e. the item). If item is holding a Sword, so `operator() (Sword&)` will be called.

The other approach is to make overloaded lambdas. It's a bit complex yet, as we don't have a library tool for that, but with C++17 it is actually easier to implement it:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct overload : Ts...
{
    using Ts::operator()...;
    template <typename... TTs>
    constexpr explicit overload(TTs&&... tts) noexcept
        : Ts{std::forward<TTs>(tts)}...
    {
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
explicit overload(Ts&&...) -> overload<std::decay_t<Ts>...>;
```

And then use it like so:

```
auto& item = inventory[0];
auto visitor = overload(
    [] (Sword& s) { std::printf("power: %d\n", s.power); },
    [] (Bottle& b) { std::printf("%s\n", b.empty? "empty" : "full"); }
);

std::visit(visitor, item);
```

If you want to understand what's happening in the `overload` struct, it's inheriting from all lambdas you're giving it, and bringing the `operator()` overloads into overload lookup (because function overloads from base classes aren't considered as candidates, so you have to `using overload`). The line after the `overload` struct is a [user-defined deduction guide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction), which means you can change the template arguments of a template struct based on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you accidentally assigned the same name to two very different classes.

One class is "Item" - and "Sword" extends it.

```
class Sword: public Item {...};
```

Another class is "Inventory" - it represents a list of items.

```
class Inventory
{
    void add(Item*) {...}
    ...
    Item** inventory;
};
```

Then you should make sure you only have one inventory, not one inventory per item. Adding stuff to this inventory should then be easy.

```
Inventory* inventory = new Inventory();
Sword* sword = new Sword(1);
inventory->add(sword);
```

---

Note: You should avoid using `new` and `delete`. Use standard containers (`std::vector`) where possible. In addition, use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) where possible. Instead of pointer-to-pointer, use a list of smart pointers:

```
Item** inventory; // works, but not so good
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>; // better
```

This is a coding-practice advice. It doesn't affect what the code really does, it's only there to reduce confusion (e.g. where to put `delete`, which corresponds to `new`).